# SQL Select Len(Col) Group by Len- etc

Tags: sql, select

I want to find the longest name in the Name column of my DB. By pixels would be ideal, but by number of bytes will be OK. This doesn't quite work:

```
Select Name, Length(Name) as LEN
From AddressFile
Group by LEN, Name
Order by LEN DESC
```

I was hoping to get something like:

```
17, Johnson-Richardson
14, AnotherLongOne
11, Smithsonian
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want bytes, you could use:

```
SELECT name, DATALENGTH(name) AS LEN
FROM addressfile
ORDER BY LEN DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
Select Name, Length(Name) as LEN
From AddressFile
Order by LEN DESC ;
```

You can add `fetch first 1 row only` (or the equivalent for your database) if you want only one value.